# Trying to get distinct values using datatable.select

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ado.net

I am trying to get data from xml file and then filter using datatable.Select() to adding the values in combobox.

But I am getting duplicate values, so I need to apply DISTINCT sort. Tried dt1.DefaultView.ToTable but no luck. still its adding duplicate items also in combobox. below is the code snippet which I am using:

```
DataTable dt1 = XMLCategory.ds.Tables["AgencyInfo"];

DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = dt1.Select("AgencyRegion='" + cmbAgPr_Region.Text + "'");
DataTable dt2 = dt1.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "AgencyMarket");
for (int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i++)
{
    cmbAgPr_Market.Items.Add(foundRows[i][1]);
}
```

Any help..

Comment: Why don't you read Xml directly and bind into combobox rather than via DataTable?

Comment: because I have to filter data depending on first column value and i need second column data to be filled in combobox after filter. please let me know if there is any better alternative.

Comment: You get duplicated in which field?

Comment: In second field and i need only distinct values from this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ with `GroupBy` to get distinct. Sample code below assumes you need to distinct in the column "columnName" with `string` type:

```
 var foundRows = dataTable.Select("...")
                  .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("columnName"), 
                           (key, group) => group.First())
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and this will solve my some more problem. Thanks Cuong and LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Minor goof fixed.**

You should be populating the listbox with the rows from dt2, not dt1. Your ToTable returns into dt2, but foundRows comes from dt1. That should fix the problem, as follows.

```
DataRow[] distinctRows = dt2.Select();
for (int i=0; i < distinctRows.Length; i++)
{
   cmbAgPr_Market.Items.Add(distinctRows[i][1]); 
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness, you could foreach over the rows in distinctRows as an alternative construct:

```
foreach(Row currentRow in distinctRows)
{
   cmbAgPr_Market.Items.Add(currentRow[1]);
}
```

Comment: above code is giving error on dt2.rows as this is a DataRowCollection and the error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to 'System.Data.DataRow[]'". Not getting the way to assign datatable value to datarow.

Comment: Okay, my stupid goof...just needed to call Select on dt2, not reference Rows property. Sorry about that!!

Comment: It worked but filter is not working now and if i am applying filter expression in dt2.select("Region='" + Region.Text + "'"). its not able to find column.